# How can I merge the objects of an array of object when three attributes in the object are equal ? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I merge the objects in an array of objects when three attributes of the object are same ?

```
var data = [
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "22.07",
"OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "21.00",
"OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "65.00",
"OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "61.00",
"OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "14.07",
"OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "12.07",
"OrderDate": "26/11/2018",
"Status": null
 },
];
```

I want to merge objects only when my Location, OrderNo and OrderDate attributes are same for the objects. I also want the qty attribute to be added when the other three attributes match.

This is my desired output

```
var output = [
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "36.14",
"OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "526209",
"Qty": "147.00",
"OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
"Status": null
 },
 {
"Location": "London",
"OrderNo": "406643",
"Qty": "12.07",
"OrderDate": "26/11/2018",
"Status": null
 },
];
```

Note in the 1st and 3rd or last object in the variable output two attributes are same but the orderDate is different.

Comment: Did you try anything? Googling maybe?

Comment: @Rajesh I tried but unable to think of a good technique

Comment: Then **PLEASE** share your attempts in question. They maybe bad but would help us

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) array methods to get what you want.

For each iteration in the `reduce` method you check with `findIndex` if there is already an object in the resulting array that match your criteria. If there is no match, you just push the current object in the resulting array. If there is a match, you sum the quantity property.

```js
var data = [
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "406643",
  "Qty": "22.07",
  "OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
  "Status": null
  },
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "526209",
  "Qty": "21.00",
  "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
  "Status": null
  },
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "526209",
  "Qty": "65.00",
  "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
  "Status": null
  },
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "526209",
  "Qty": "61.00",
  "OrderDate": "01/03/2019",
  "Status": null
  },
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "406643",
  "Qty": "14.07",
  "OrderDate": "28/11/2018",
  "Status": null
  },
  {
  "Location": "London",
  "OrderNo": "406643",
  "Qty": "12.07",
  "OrderDate": "26/11/2018",
  "Status": null
  }
];

data = data.reduce((acc, v) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(o => {
    return  o.Location === v.Location && 
            o.OrderNo === v.OrderNo && 
            o.OrderDate === v.OrderDate
  });
  
  if (index >= 0) {
    acc[index].Qty = (Number(acc[index].Qty) + Number(v.Qty)).toFixed(2);
  } else {
    acc.push(v);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hey @Scooby It would be nice if you upvote and accept an answer to your question. It helps other users to find a solution to their problem plus rewards users answering questions. Cheers.